# Finding Hausdorff Distance

Tags: hausdorff-distance

I have a question on the wording of the task

> Find in $R^2$ the Hausdorff distance $h(S_7(a),(-9)S_1(b))$, where $a(2,-1)^T, b(-1,3)^T$

The first object is a circle with radius $7$ centered at point $a$, but in the second circle $-9$ what does it refer to? Do I need to multiply the radius of the circle by $-9$ or what operation should I do?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it might mean that you multiply all the points in $S_1(b)$ by $-9$, coordinate-wise.

Comment: You need to find the place in your class notes or textbook where this notation is defined. The definitions are not universal, so any answer you receive will just be a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s impossible to tell without the notation explicitly defined.  However. A common use of the notation is as follows:
If $X$ is a set, then $kX$ is the set $\{ k x : x \in X \}$.

So, in your problem,
$-9 S_1(b) = \{ -9 x : x \text{ is a point of the unit circle centered at b} \}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suppose your interpretation seems to be true.